# Sum of the length of the perpendiculars - property of equliateral triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

> Consider an equilateral triangle $ABC$ where
>
> $P$ is a point on $AB$,
>   $Q$ is a point
>   on $BC$.
>
> Suppose we draw perpendiculars from $P$ to other sides. Let $s_1$ be the
>   sum of the length of these perpendiculars.
>
> Suppose we draw perpendiculars from $Q$ to other sides. Let $s_2$ be the
>   sum of the length of these perpendiculars.
>
> Then, will $s_1$ be $s_2$?

This doubt came while going to through the solution given in this website [here](http://goo.gl/TP5o84), According to the solution there, $s_1$ must be equal to $s_2$.

**My attempt to see whether $s_1$ is equal to $s_2$**

Using [Viviani's_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viviani's_theorem), sum of perpendicular drawn from all sides to any arbitrary point is equal to altitude.

I tried to see if this is any possible extension of this theorem. But, finally came to the conclusion that we cannot use Viviani's_theorem for this because, the point lies on a side and we are calculating sum of perpendiculars from each side.

I tried to split the triangle and use Pythagorean theorem. But all my efforts did not succeed.

I am also not sure whether this is true (i.e., $s_1=s_2$).

Comment: $s_1=s_2=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}k$ where $k$ is the length of a side of the equilateral triangle (because each perpendicular is inclined at an angle $30^o$ to the side).

Comment: oh, yes, I feel bad that I missed this. I have to improve a lot :(. Thanks @ almagest

Comment: @almagest, if you can explain a bit more, it will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The triangles $PAM,PLB$ are similar. Both are half an equilateral triangle. So $\frac{PM}{PA}=\frac{PL}{PB}=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$.

Note that if you reflect $PAM$ in the line $PM$ you get an equilateral triangle side $PA$. So $AM$ is half $PA$ and you can then get $PM$ by Pythagoras' Theorem. Hence the $\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$.

So $PM+PL=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}(PA+PB)=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}AB$ or if you prefer the height of the triangle.

Comment: So the Sun of perpendicular will be independent of the position of the points?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.